# Перегрузка с первым необязательным параметром

Tags: перегрузка-операторов, typescript

Как написать код с такой логикой?

```
function test(data: {x}, f: Function);
function test(f: Function);

function test(data: {x}, f: Function) {
    if (!f) {
        f = data;
        data = {x: 111};
    }

    return f(data);
}

test({x: 17}, t => 0);
test(t => 0);
```

Компилируется он правильно, но выдаёт две ошибки

```
function test(data, f) {
    if (!f) {
        f = data;
        data = { x: 111 };
    }
    return f(data);
}
test({ x: 17 }, function (t) { return 0; });
test(function (t) { return 0; });
```

Попробовать можно здесь: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813922/overload-with-first-optional-parameter).

Comment: `return f(data.x);`

Comment: @Igor, как это связано с вопросом вообще?

Comment: Прошу прощения, а какой вопрос?

Comment: @Igor, при компиляции в строках 2 и 6 ошибки. Как их исправить?

Comment: @Igor, немного поправил код, чтобы не возникало этого момента.

Comment: @Igor, вроде разобрался.

Comment: спасибо, полезная вещь, буду знать.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33813922/4928642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл способ:

```
function test(data: {x}, f: Function);
function test(f: Function);

//function test(data: {x} | Function, f?: Function) {
function test(data, f?) {
    if (!f) {
        f = data as Function;
        data = {x: 111};
    }

    return f(data);
}
```

Таки вызовы компилируются:

```
test({x: 17}, t => 0);
test(t => 0);
```

А на такие выдаётся ошибка:

```
test({x: 17});
test(0);
test(t => 0, t => 0);
```

Любой из следующих вариантов подходит:

```
function test(data: {x} | Function, f?: Function) {
function test(data, f?) {
```

А внутри следует использовать явное приведение типа:

```
f = data as Function;
```